# How to get index and value of an item in python list?

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point

I have a list like this:

```
lst = [None,None,None,'0.141675556588',None,None,None,'0.268087046988']
```

I want to get any number >0.1 and put them as well as their list index in another list. In this list like this:

```
another_lst = [['3', 0.14], ['7', 0.26]]
```

I have tried this code so far, which has not been very useful:

```
another_lst = []

for position, item in enumerate(lst):
    if float(item) > 0.1:
        another_lst += [position, item]
```

Need help. Thanks!

Comment: You have to check that `item` is not `None` otherwise an exception will be raise. Modify the condition: `if float(item) > 0.1:` to: `if item and float(item) > 0.1:`

Comment: use `.append` instead of `+=` which is similar to `.extend`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
lst = [None,None,"string", None,'0.141675556588',None,None,"hi how are you", None,'0.268087046988']

positions = [[i, a] for i, a in enumerate(lst) if a is not None and not ''.join(a.split()).isalpha() and float(a) > 0.1]
```

Output:

```
[[4, '0.141675556588'], [9, '0.268087046988']]
```

Comment: What if there is a string inside the list like [None, 'string', '3']. How do I do the filter then?

Comment: @0x1 Please see my recent edit. The best way is to use `isalpha`

Comment: I still get the same error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float`

Comment: Okay. I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @0x1 glad to help! I just posted updated final output.

Comment: Okay. Just a hypothetical. What if the string had two or more words. Will this still work?

Comment: Aah, you joined them up. Clever! Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @0x1 You are welcome! Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is because you're trying to do `float(None)`. Have a check at the beginning of the for-loop to filter out those Nones:

```
for position, item in enumerate(a):
    if item is not None and float(item) > 0.1:
        another_lst.append([position, item])
```

Also, use `another_lst.append()` function instead of `+=`. Sometimes the latter can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: What if there is a string inside the list like  [None, 'string', '3']. How do I do the filter then?